# How to initialize an array class with constructor C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, oop, initialization

i'm trying to initialize an array of a class, but i can only do this if i specify every object of the array, for example:

```
class Pixel{
private:
    int color;
public:
    Pixel(int color):color(color){}
};

class Screen{
private:
    Pixel screen[1920][1080];   
public:
    Screen(){
    //code//
    //i was trying to use for, to determinate each pixel color from a certain area
    //but i cannot, bc i would have to do something like this:
    screen[1920][1080] = {{Pixel(1),Pixel(1),Pixel(1),Pixel(1)...1080 times},{Pixel(2)
    ,Pixel(2), Pixel(2)...1080 times}...1918 times}
    //as you can see, is nearly impossible to do this in this way.
    }
};
```

there is a native way to initialize this array with fors or something like this?

(that code is just an EXAMPLE with the exact same logic, its not from my project)

Comment: You can write a default constructor for your `Pixel` class. Or better yet just give the parameter in your ctor a default value

Comment: Use a `vector` instead of an array.

Comment: Also, your 2D array has an aspect ratio of 9:16 whereas you might really want 16:9 as in the TVs and monitors, etc.

Comment: You can use a `for` loop (two nested, in fact) to assign initial values in the constructor

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your code:

1. Your Pixel type requires explicit initalization. Is that wise? @perivesta suggests providing a default constructor; or a default parameter to your existing constructor.

   Another option would  be reconsidering whether you even need a proper `Pixel` class at all. Perhaps it might be enough to just have

   ```
   using Pixel = std::int32_t;
   ```

   or whichever size a pixel is supposed to have. If a pixel needs fancy methods, then a struct wrapping the basic value, but without specifying any constructors or destructors, i.e. using the [rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)
2. As @digito_evo explains - that's too large of an array to place on the stack; your program might crash for this reason alone, even if you were able to initialize your array. Consider having your `Screen` class allocate space on the heap, e.g. via [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) member, or an `std::vector` like @NathanOliver suggests (both of them get allocated on the heap).

   Read more about the heap and the stack: [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/79923/1593077)
3. Use of magic numbers: 1920, 1080 - don't just type them in, say what they mean... have static class (constexpr) constants for these dimensions. For more on this point, see the [C++ coding guideline against magic numbers](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Res-magic).

Answer (score 1):

Your 2D array `screen` is too big (about **8 MB**!!) to fit on the stack. You certainly don't want a stack overflow in your program. Therefore use a `vector` instead.

Also, a *color* variable doesn't need to be of type `int`. What are you going to do with **32** bits really?? Usually, ***8*** bits is sufficient so I switched to `unsigned char`.

Since you want a for-loop, have a look at this:

```
#include <vector>


class Pixel
{
public:
    Pixel( const unsigned char color = 0 )
    : m_color( color )
    {
    }

private:
    unsigned char m_color;
};

class Screen
{
public:
    Screen( const std::size_t rowCount = 1920, const std::size_t colCount = 1080 )
    : screen( rowCount, std::vector<Pixel>( colCount ) )
    {
        for ( std::size_t row { }; row < rowCount; ++row )
        {
            for ( std::size_t col { }; col < colCount; ++col )
            {
                screen[ row ][ col ] = Pixel( static_cast<unsigned char>( row ) + 1 );
            }
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector< std::vector<Pixel> > screen; // a vector of vectors
};

int main( )
{
    Screen scrn;
}
```